# Using a sample obtained via McMc for Monte Carlo

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, independence, monte-carlo, markov-process

Suppose we have a sample obtained via McMc. In order to use this sample for Monte-Carlo we need the sample to be independent. However our sample obtained via McMc is not independent, how can we justify using this? I think I know of a tactic which allows us to take every Nth value of the sample to minimise the dependency. Can we use this sample without this tactic?

I ask because my lecturer used a sample to obtain an estimate of the mean, however he did not take every Nth value.

I think there is a hole in my understanding but I am not sure where.

Many thanks gang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with simply averaging. The expectation of a set of correlated samples from the population distribution will still be the population mean.

Taking every Nth value will simply throw away information in the full data set.

The only issue is in computing its variance or its standard deviation; however, if you have a sufficiently large run (once you've hit the stationary distribution), you can form fairly precise estimates of the autocorrelation function out to some high lag (say, about as far as the gaps you were going to leave where you were assuming independence), and so often get quite good estimates of the standard deviation.

Comment: (+1) Indeed using a subsample of the MCMC sample to compute expectations as averages is suboptimal and leads to an increase in variance. Evaluations of the variance of MCMC estimators are available, check eg papers by Rosenthal, Jones, Flegal.